# What does --> do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, comments

I have been unable to find any reference to this statement in any book, manual, or site. As far as I can tell, it functions exactly as a `//` comment. For example:

```
console.log("1");
--> console.log("2");
console.log("3");
```

will print

```
1
3
```

What I'm curious about is exactly what the difference between `-->` and `//` is, if any exists, and also why `-->` seems to completely absent from all the JavaScript references I've seen - the only reason I found out about it at all was because I accidentally typed it into Adobe Dreamweaver, and it was highlighted as a comment. Thanks!

Edit: [Here is a functional jsFiddle demonstrating the behavior](http://jsfiddle.net/A7Hu2/).

Edit 2: I've tested further, and I've discovered a few things.

- This only works if there are exactly two dashes. `->` and `--->` will throw errors.
- This only works with a "greater than" symbol. `--<` will throw an error.
- This will not work in the middle of or at the end of a line. `console.log("1"); --> console.log("2");` will throw an error.

Comment: Possibly related to this well-known question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-this-operator

Comment: The chrome's debugger says its illigal character.

Comment: @SumanBogati Really? My Chrome console (version 32.0.1700.107) treats it exactly the way it's described in my post. What version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: Do apology, it was my mistake, not showing anymore but was earlier  because of other reason perhaps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that the JavaScript engine, forgiving as always, is silently ignoring the line because it looks like the end of an HTML comment (`<!-- -->`). JavaScript inlined in HTML has historically been wrapped in an HTML comment so that browsers that don't support JavaScript would not try to parse it.

---

**Edit:**

I've done some research, and this is indeed the case.

From V8's [scanner.cc](http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/scanner.cc):

> If there is an HTML comment end '-->' at the beginning of a
>   line (with only whitespace in front of it), we treat the rest
>   of the line as a comment. This is in line with the way
>   SpiderMonkey handles it.

From Rhino's [Comment.java](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/blob/master/src/org/mozilla/javascript/ast/Comment.java):

> JavaScript effectively has five comment types:
>
> 1. `// line comments`
> 2. `/* block comments */`
> 3. `/** jsdoc comments */`
> 4. `<!-- html-open line comments`
> 5. `^\s*--> html-close line comments`
>
> The first three should be familiar to Java programmers. JsDoc comments
>   are really just block comments with some conventions about the formatting
>   within the comment delimiters. Line and block comments are described in the
>   Ecma-262 specification.

Note that the `-->` comment is **not** part of the Ecma-262 specification.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a comment.  If you see it as a comment inside of code, then its probably showing as some kind of hanging chad HTML comment instead of the normal "//".

What's happening in this case is you are comparing using the greater than and then subtracting 1.  Here are some examples...

```
var x = 3; var y = 3; console.log(x --> y);
```

**false**  and x is now 2

If you place the normal comment characters "//", you'll get a syntax error (which you should)

The reason this is working as a comment is because it is returning as undefined.  This is not safe to use as a comment.  Oddly enough, it works fine in Chrome and you can throw all kinds of characters at it if you start the line with "-->".

```
--> something for nothing ~!@#@#%$#%^$&%^&*()_+_=-=[]\];'\||?>;';;; alert('test'),,143187132458
```

However, within IE 11, it is always a syntax error.  Very cool find

Comment: Do you see any operator before `-->` in the OP's example? FWIW, `-- > console.log(...)` (space between `--` and `>` throws a syntax error, whereas `console.log(x -- > y);` wouldn't.

Comment: -1 this doesn't give false because of that. The way you're putting it -1 is only substracted after you used the variable. During the comparison x is still 3 thus equal. `var x = 3; var y = 3; console.log(x --== y);` gives true

Comment: Your statement is only true when you did `var x = 3; var y = 3; console.log(--x > y);`

Comment: @FelixKling That's partly my point. // can be used as an inline comment and so I was comparing this to --> which has to be at the start of the line.  The author has edited to reflect.  Sorry if this was confusing.